# Installing Angular / latest version

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to install the newest version of `angular/cli` but I get an error:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2
>   (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ETARGET npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for socks@~2.3.2. npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist. npm ERR! notarget npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'socks-proxy-agent' npm ERR! notarget
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

If I try to install manually this version "npm i -g socks@2.3.2" I get a message

> No matching version found for socks@2.3.2

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

```
npm -v
6.13.1

node -v
v13.2.0
```

### **I finded the problem:**

here in my work we are using "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" and it was not updating to a new version some libraries. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Im not sure if this would fully solve your problem but I would suggest running installing node via nvm if you arent already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was searching about nvm... But i'm runing at windows and i saw this message on the documentation of it: nvm does not support Windows (see #284), but may work in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) depending on the version of WSL. Do you know another way ?

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that your platform OS is windows. if so, then right click on your command prompt and then click `Run as asministrator` to open your command promit in Admin mode. Then try this:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: and what about this: npm install -g @angular/cli?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Yarn Package Manager](https://yarnpkg.com) instead.

`yarn add --dev @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the `cli`, Clear any cache on your machine, then try to update the `cli`

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```